# Disable drag and drop file uploads in syncfusion

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion

Is there anyway to disable drag and drop functionality when the folder is empty. I am using syncfusion file manager and react js just to browse the folder and file from node server.
I have written following code inside the return of react component:

```
<div className='control-section'>
        <FileManagerComponent
          id='file'
          view='LargeIcons'
          enablePersistence={true}
          ajaxSettings={{
            async: true,
            url: hostUrl,
            downloadUrl: hostUrl + '/Download',
            getImageUrl: hostUrl + '/GetImage',
          }}
          detailsViewSettings={{
            columns: [
              {
                field: 'name',
                headerText: 'File Name',
                minWidth: 120,
                width: 'auto',
                customAttributes: { class: 'e-fe-grid-name' },
                template: '${name}',
              },
            ],
          }}
          contextMenuSettings={{
            visible: false,
          }}
          fileSelect={onFileSelect}
          success={onSuccess}
          failure={onFailure}
        >
          <Inject services={[DetailsView]} />
        </FileManagerComponent>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement by setting dropArea property of uploadObj as null in the success event of File Manager as demonstrated in the below code snippet,

```
    var len, drag;
export class Overview extends SampleBase {

 }
  created() {
    var file =document.getElementsByClassName('e-filemanager')[0].ej2_instances[0];
    drag = file.uploadObj.dropArea;   //to store the drop area element
  }

success(args) {
if (args.action == 'read' && args.result.files.length == 0) {
file.uploadObj.dropArea = null;  
} else {
file.uploadObj.dropArea = drag;
}
}

render() {
return (
  <div>
    <div className="control-section">
      <FileManagerComponent
        created={this.created}
        success={this.success}
      >
      </FileManagerComponent>
}
```

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wqgwtz-2p8gp9

API Link : https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/api/uploader/#droparea

Comment: Thank you, this codes does work but even the drag and drop upload is disabled,  the view area still show Folder icon and text 'This folder is empty Drag files here to upload'. I want to remove this information.

Comment: https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/158259/prevent-drag-drop-for-upload-change-default-message-if-folder-is-empty Please refer this forum